# Two Chemicals A and B are mixed together in a vat (ODE problem)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Two chemical species, $A$ and $B$, are mixed together in a vat. $A$ turns into $B$ at a certain rate $k_1$. Meanwhile, the reverse reaction also occurs, with $B$ turning back to $A$ at a different rate $k_2$. If $x_A$ stands for the quantity of species $A$ and $x_B$ stands for the quantity of species $B$, then
>
> $$\begin{aligned}\frac{dx_A}{dt} &= -k_1x_A+k_2x_B\\ \frac{dx_B}{dt} &= k_1x_A-k_2x_B\end{aligned}$$
>
> (a) By taking derivatives show that $x_A$ satisfies a second order ODE.
>
> (b) Obtain the general solution for $x_A(t)$

I've been working on this question for quie a while now, and cant seem to figure how to do part (a). Im pretty sure I will be able to do part (b) though. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first equation can be written as
$$
k_2x_B=\dot x_A+k_1x_A.
$$
Now use this to eliminate $x_B$ from the second equation,
$$
\ddot x_A+k_1\dot x_A=k_2\dot x_B=k_2(k_1x_A−k_2x_B)=k_2(k_1x_A−(\dot x_A+k_1x_A))
$$
which now is a second order DE in $x_A$.